# Increment product quantity stock on payment failure

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

Could anyone tell me how can I increment my product quantity stock when an order gets fails?
I'm using Magento 2.3.5 and using a customized payment gateway.

The scenario is when I'm placing an order and proceeding with the custom payment gateway and returns with a failed order. At this moment I need to increase the product quantity stock.

Is there any way of doing this? Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are catching the payment failure in javascript ? Then what you need to do is just to make an ajax call to a new action where you will handle this by interacting with `stock_items`.

EDIT : I don't think magento decrease the stock if the payment fail. That would be a strange behaviour.